# How can I return the values to use in the first function?

Tags: javascript, return, return-value

I'm currently working a summer course in programming to learn more while school is on summer break. In one of the assignements, I need to use the given variables to calculate the power of two values. I dont know the values beforehand, as the website generates different values when I try to run the program. I've hit my head against the wall for the whole day so any help nudging me in the right direction is appreciated!! Example of the assignment below.

```
**function laskuFunktio() {
    var luku = noudaArvo("luku");
    var eksp = noudaArvo("eksponentti");
    
    console.log("Luku " + luku + " potenssiin " + eksp + " on:");
    console.log(laskePotenssi(luku, eksp));
}**

function noudaArvo() { 
    luku = document.getElementById("luku").value        
    eksp = document.getElementById("eksponentti").value;
    return ???
}

function laskePotenssi() {
    if (eksp === 0) {
        tulos = 1;
    }
    var tulos = Math.pow(luku, eksp);
    return tulos 
}
```

The first function is predetermined so I cant edit it, but the assignments are made possible without editing it or accessing the HTML files. The return statement was just edited by me to sho where I currently am stuck. Thanks for any help once more!

Comment: Well, if you want help with what the return value of `noudaArvo()` should be, it might be useful to explain what the function is supposed to do as the names you are using for functions and variables are not self-explanatory (not for English speakers, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the way noudaArvo() is called. It accepts a single parameter and expects a return value. The parameter it's passing appears to be the ID of the element it wants the value of. So don't hardcode the IDs in getElementByID(), use a parameter (which your noudaArvo() function header is missing)  Return that single value, laskuFunktio() is calling it twice to get both values.

laskePotenssi() needs to accept two parameters. Here's an example of a function with 2 parameters and using them within the function body to return the sum of them. Does this help?

```
function test(param1, param2){
    foobar = param1 + param2;

    return foobar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions may only return one thing, but it appears you'd like `noudaArvo()` to return the values of both the base and exponent. This can be done by answering an array ("one thing" that can hold two values).

Your first attempt at `laskePotenssi` uses the variable `telos` before declaring it. Make that `let` declaration first.

This can be done with prettier, more concise code, but I've maintained as much as I could from the OP as instruction.

```js
function noudaArvo() { 
    luku = document.getElementById("luku").value        
    eksp = document.getElementById("eksponentti").value;
    return [luku, eksp];
}

function laskePotenssi(luku, eksp) {
    let tulos;
    if (eksp === 0) {
        tulos = 1;
    } else {
      tulos = Math.pow(luku, eksp);
    }
    return tulos 
}

function compute() {
  let [luku, eksp] = noudaArvo();
  let result = laskePotenssi(luku, eksp)
  alert(`the answer is ${result}`)
}
```

```html
<input id="luku" placeholder="enter base"/>
<input id="eksponentti" placeholder="enter exponent"/>
<button onclick="compute()">Compute</button>
```